# How to write Pyspark DataFrame to XML Format?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue, apache-spark-xml

I'm working on a Glue ETL Job that basically reads a dataframe in Pyspark and should output data in XML Format.
I've searched a lot for the solution and the code fails at the particular write statement shown below:

```
df.write.format('com.databricks.spark.xml').options(rowTag='book', rootTag='books').save('newbooks.xml')
```

The Glue Version I'm currently using is Glue 3.0 - Spark 3.1, Scala 2 and Python 3.
Since I'm trying to use the **Spark-XML** library I have tried including the following **jars** as **dependents** in the **Glue** Script:

```
spark-xml_2.10-0.3.5,
spark-xml_2.11-0.7.0,
spark-xml_2.12-0.14.0,
spark-xml_2.13-0.14.0
```

The different errors I'm seeing with different versions are as follows:

```
An error occurred while calling o92.save. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/java8/JFunction0$mcD$sp
```

```
An error occurred while calling o95.save. java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DirectOutputCommitter not found
```

An error occurred while calling `o95.save. scala/$less$colon$less`

I've found a similar question posted previously by someone else and tried those approaches and they don't seem to work anymore. Has someone faced a similar issue recently? If yes, can you shed some light on the resolution?

Answer (score 2):

First see what is the Scala version for your Spark.
if it is **2.11** then go with spark-xml_**2.11**-0.7.0
or if it is **2.12** then go with spark-xml_**2.12**-0.14.0 likewise the rest.

now spark-xml have the dependencies with the other jars as well. Try to use that as well with your spark-xml jar.

1. commons-io version - 2.11.0
2. txw2 version - 3.0.2
3. xmlschema-core -2.3.0

*note*- you can try the above dependency jars with different versions as well. The jars version is suitable for the **spark-xml_2.12-0.14.0**

Hope this will help.

Reference - https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml/blob/master/build.sbt